# × TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined when I change data in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a React app. It has a button "Add", once you click it, it adds a couple of input fields. Every line of inputs has a button "X" to remove the line from screen.
The issue, I want to fix, happens after removing all lines and adding a new one, when I change data into the input. It throws an error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined". Please any advices to fix the issue. Thanks.

```
handleChange
src/App.js:10
   7 | let index = event.target.id;
   8 | if (event.target.name === "name") {
   9 |   let newArr = [...datas];
> 10 |   newArr[index].name = event.target.value;
     | ^  11 |   setDatas(newArr);
  12 | }
  13 | if (event.target.name === "gender") {
View compiled

TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

---

My code is below:

```
import { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let index = event.target.id;
    if (event.target.name === "name") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index].name = event.target.value;
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "gender") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index].gender = event.target.value;
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
  };

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    let newItems = datas.filter((product) => product.id !== id);
    setDatas(newItems);
  };
  console.log(datas);
  return (
    <>
      {datas.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <input
              name="name"
              id={data.id}
              value={data.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <input
              name="gender"
              id={data.id}
              value={data.gender}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(data.id)}>X</button>
          </li>
        );
      })}

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter((prevState) => prevState + 1);
          setDatas([...datas, { id: counter, name: "", gender: "" }]);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the ID of the element to be the index you're iterating over in order to assign to `newArr[index]` - currently, the ID is the `data.id` instead, which is presumably not the index.

You're also mutating the state at the moment - create a copy instead of mutating.

```
      {datas.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <input
              name="name"
              id={index}
              value={data.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

And avoid mutation with:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const index = event.target.id;
    if (event.target.name === "name") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = ({ ...newArr[index], name: event.target.value });
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
```

and use the same pattern for the gender as well.

Another option, to avoid having dynamic IDs (which is a code smell) is to curry the index into the handler first.

```
const handleChange = index => event => {
```

and then change

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

to

```
onChange={handleChange(index)}
```